# warning with triple pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I received a warning for this code .

```
Warning { 

` del2_.c: In function ‘addIntoCell’:`

  `del2_.c:401:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘resizeArray’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`

  `del2_.c:378:6: note: expected ‘struct t_grapheVertex ***’ but argument is of type ‘struct  t_grapheVertex **`

}
```

this is how I define the function :
`void resizeArray(t_grapheVertex ***ele)`

and here is the warning when I call the function :
    `resizeArray(&(*cell)->elements);`

and this is the structure for the cell :

```
typedef struct st_cell
{
    int nbElements;
    struct st_cell* next;
    t_grapheVertex* elements;
} t_cell;


void resizeArray(t_grapheVertex ***ele){
    t_grapheVertex *temp;
    int newSize;
    newSize = arraySize*increaseRate ;
    temp = realloc(*ele , sizeof(int)*newSize);
    if(**ele == NULL)
    {
        printf("fail to resize\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("resized succesfully\n");
        **ele=temp;
        arraySize = newSize ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the diagnostic message already explains it all very precisely. Which part of that message don't you understand?

Comment: I thought that there is a way to make a triple pointer for this without store a double pointer in the st_cell , but that seems to be impossible .
your comments was very helpful ,thanks a lot .

Answer (score 2):

(*cell)->elements give you a pointer, then ampersand given you a **double** pointer. Same time, you expect a **triple** pointer at resizeArray() function - do you really mean this?

If possible, could you share the code of resizeArray?